# MT7621A se reinicia con kernel de linux 5.0.19-rt10

Tags: linux

Estoy trabajando en el desarrollo de un producto con el SoC Mediatek MT7621A junto al kernel de linux 5.0.19-rt10.

Me encuentro con reinicios al cabo de unas horas (los cuales son por watchdog). Para conseguir debuggear, he activado ciertas opciones del kernel como `Detect soft lockups` y `Detect hung tasks`. Con esto he llegado a obtener el stack trace de algún fallo relacionado con spinlocks. No todos los stack trace son iguales, pero sí que todos coinciden en que acaban en `task_blocks_on_rt_mutex()`

Aquí os dejo un ejemplo:

```
[ 2370.270000] 000: Kernel bug detected[#1]:
[ 2370.270000] 000: CPU: 0 PID: 799 Comm: agsPoll0 Tainted: G           O      5.0.19-rt10 #5
[ 2370.270000] 000: $ 0   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000001
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000001
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000001
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: $ 4   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000001
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda6e40
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: $ 8   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda5be0
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda5be0
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000001
[ 2370.270000] 000:  ffffffff
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: $12   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00014b40
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: $16   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda5be0
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda6e40
[ 2370.270000] 000:  81002a60
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc0bd30
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: $20   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda72ec
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8071e520
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: $24   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  80010580
[ 2370.270000] 000:          
[ 2370.270000] 000:          
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: $28   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8e722000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc0bca8
[ 2370.270000] 000:  80720000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8007a2a0
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: Hi    : 000227df
[ 2370.270000] 000: Lo    : 19f38000
[ 2370.270000] 000: epc   : 8007a2c0 task_blocks_on_rt_mutex+0x6c/0x300
[ 2370.270000] 000: ra    : 8007a2a0 task_blocks_on_rt_mutex+0x4c/0x300
[ 2370.270000] 000: Status: 11000402
[ 2370.270000] 000: KERNEL 
[ 2370.270000] 000: EXL 
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: Cause : 50800034 (ExcCode 0d)
[ 2370.270000] 000: PrId  : 0001992f (MIPS 1004Kc)
[ 2370.270000] 000: Modules linked in:
[ 2370.270000] 000:  prd_phy_controller(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  csl_mng_module(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  csl_packet_module(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  mac(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  alb_critical_lock(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  phyif(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  ttstools(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  gpio_bb(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  loopprotect(O)

[ 2370.270000] 000:  sys_mng(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  alb_workqueues(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  iptable_filter
[ 2370.270000] 000:  [last unloaded: nf_nat]
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: Process agsPoll0 (pid: 799, threadinfo=ef6213bf, task=9369b08c, tls=00000000)
[ 2370.270000] 000: Stack :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8100df20
[ 2370.270000] 000:  80055d30
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda608c
[ 2370.270000] 000:  80723c40
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda72ec
[ 2370.270000] 000:  81002a60
[ 2370.270000] 000:  805ed164
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000:        
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  81002a60
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda6e40
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc0bd30
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda72ec
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8071e520
[ 2370.270000] 000:  805eb030
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000:        
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000009
[ 2370.270000] 000:  81002a60
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  805ed1e0
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  81002a60
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc0bd30
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000:        
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8071e520
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8071e6e0
[ 2370.270000] 000:  80720000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  805eb2bc
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000003
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8f4f0c40
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000:        
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  81002f20
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc0bd30
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc3c9e0
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000009
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc0bd3c
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc3ce2c
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000:        
[ 2370.270000] 000:  ...
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: Call Trace:
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8007a2c0>] task_blocks_on_rt_mutex+0x6c/0x300
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805eb030>] rt_spin_lock_slowlock_locked+0xbc/0x2fc
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805eb2bc>] rt_spin_lock_slowlock+0x4c/0x70
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805ed430>] rt_spin_lock+0x68/0x78
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<800149c8>] mips_cm_lock_other+0x13c/0x1e8
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<800104b0>] mips_smp_send_ipi_mask+0x13c/0x20c
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<80055cf8>] check_preempt_curr+0x98/0xb4
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<80055d30>] ttwu_do_wakeup.isra.93+0x1c/0x110
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<80056814>] try_to_wake_up+0x20c/0x46c
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<800806b0>] __handle_irq_event_percpu+0x7c/0x178
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<800807dc>] handle_irq_event_percpu+0x30/0x78
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8008087c>] handle_irq_event+0x58/0xb0
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<800855e0>] handle_level_irq+0x10c/0x1f0
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8007fc20>] generic_handle_irq+0x40/0x58
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8031c980>] gic_handle_shared_int+0xcc/0x19c
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8007fc20>] generic_handle_irq+0x40/0x58
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805ed8b0>] do_IRQ+0x18/0x24
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8031baf8>] plat_irq_dispatch+0x90/0x110
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<80006ca8>] except_vec_vi_end+0xb8/0xc4
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805ed08c>] _raw_spin_unlock_irq+0x18/0x4c
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805eae60>] __rt_mutex_slowlock+0x110/0x224
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805eb378>] rt_mutex_slowlock_locked+0x98/0x284
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805eb5cc>] rt_mutex_slowlock.constprop.25+0x68/0xc4
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805eb790>] __rt_mutex_lock_state+0x90/0xbc
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<c074d938>] AGSPollLoopStats+0xa0/0x10c [mac]
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8004d020>] kthread_worker_fn+0xc8/0x140
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8004cee0>] kthread+0x118/0x148
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<800067ac>] ret_from_kernel_thread+0x14/0x1c
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: Code:
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000 
[ 2370.270000] 000:  2c420003 
[ 2370.270000] 000:  38420001 
[ 2370.270000] 000: <00020336>
[ 2370.270000] 000:  ae710018 
[ 2370.270000] 000:  ae72001c 
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8e220038 
[ 2370.270000] 000:  ae620024 
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8e220160 
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.830000] 000: ---[ end trace 0000000000000002 ]---
[ 2370.840000] 000: Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
[ 2370.840000] 000: Rebooting in 10 seconds..
```

Luego, de manera infructuosa, he activado en el kernel el debug de los locks, ya que nada más arrancar el sistema me salta un warning de un posible deadlock, el cual se encuentra dentro del kernel.

¿Alguna sugerencia para proceder? ¿A alguien le ha pasado algo parecido?

Comment: Podrias intentar con un kernel mas reciente?

Comment: usar otros kernel's podria descartar que sea un bug del que estas usando

Comment: Utilizando el parche de tiempo real, hay un cambio grande relacionado con las softirqs, tendría que adaptar todo el sistema @eftshift0